# Why don't Christians believe in the Gospel Of Barnabas?

Tags: canon, pseudepigrapha

The Gospel Of Barnabas is one of the 2 additional Gospel discovered than present in Bible which has an clearly distinct prespective about Jesus (PBUH) and his death so why Christians do not believe in Gospel Of Barnabas?

Comment: Welcome! A question very similar to this one has already been asked, so this one has been closed as a duplicate. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Some people who call themselves Christians do